java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libc++_shared.so" not found
I am trying to use the Zoom Video SDK for video calling and other purposes. When I added the Zoom SDK to my app, it threw the following error. I have tried all the solutions available on StackOverflow and GitHub, but with no luck.
E/AndroidRuntime(13924): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libc++_shared.so" not found
E/AndroidRuntime(13924):    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1081)
E/AndroidRuntime(13924):    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1003)
E/AndroidRuntime(13924):    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1765)
E/AndroidRuntime(13924):    at us.zoom.util.AndroidContext.<clinit>(AndroidContext.java:1)
E/AndroidRuntime(13924):    at us.zoom.internal.SDKApplication.onSDKCreated(SDKApplication.java:39)
E/AndroidRuntime(13924):    at us.zoom.internal.SDKApplication.initializeForSDK(SDKApplication.java:12)
E/AndroidRuntime(13924):    at us.zoom.internal.ZoomVideoSDKImpl.initialize(ZoomVideoSDKImpl.java:2)
E/AndroidRuntime(13924):    at com.flutterzoom.videosdk.FlutterZoomVideoSdkPlugin.initSdk(FlutterZoomVideoSdkPlugin.java:708)
E/AndroidRuntime(13924):    at com.flutterzoom.videosdk.FlutterZoomVideoSdkPlugin.onMethodCall(FlutterZoomVideoSdkPlugin.java:130)
E/AndroidRuntime(13924):    at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:267)
E/AndroidRuntime(13924):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.invokeHandler(DartMessenger.java:292)
E/AndroidRuntime(13924):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.lambda$dispatchMessageToQueue$0$io-flutter-embedding-engine-dart-DartMessenger(DartMessenger.java:319)
E/AndroidRuntime(13924):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(Unknown Source:12)
E/AndroidRuntime(13924):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:959)
E/AndroidRuntime(13924):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
E/AndroidRuntime(13924):    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:232)
E/AndroidRuntime(13924):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:317)
E/AndroidRuntime(13924):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8674)
E/AndroidRuntime(13924):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(13924):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:580)
E/AndroidRuntime(13924):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:886)

I am using the following SDK from Zoom:
  flutter_zoom_videosdk: ^1.11.2

Can you help me find a solution for this? Thanks for your help.
